# Change value for ID for each row in the quarter where the value is one

Tags: python, pandas

I have customer data by quarter for the last 2 quarters. If the customer becomes a new customer on the 1st or 2nd month of the quarter I would like to change the values for each month in the quarter for that customer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date', 'ID', 'New_customer', 'Good_customer', 'Quarter'])

df =df.append({'date':'2021-04-01','ID':111, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':2},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-05-01','ID':111, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':2},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-06-01','ID':111, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':2},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-01-01','ID':111, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':1},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-02-01','ID':111, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':1},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-03-01','ID':111, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':1},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-04-01','ID':222, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':2},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-05-01','ID':222, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':2},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-06-01','ID':222, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':2},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-01-01','ID':222, 'New_customer':1, 'Good_customer':'n', 'Quarter':1},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-02-01','ID':222, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':1},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-03-01','ID':222, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':1},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-05-01','ID':333, 'New_customer':1, 'Good_customer':'n', 'Quarter':2},ignore_index = True)
df =df.append({'date':'2021-06-01','ID':333, 'New_customer':0, 'Good_customer':'y', 'Quarter':2},ignore_index = True)
```

Customer 222 became a new customer on 2021-01-01 in quarter 1 I would like to change the zeros to ones for the next two months of the year. Same for customer 333 who became a new customer 2021-06-01 the second month of quarter 2.

I've tried

```
t3 = t3.sort_values(['QUARTER', 'ID', 'New_customer'], ascending=False)
s = ~t3.duplicated(['ID'], keep='first')
t3['New_customer'] = t3['ID'].map(t3[s].set_index('ID')['New_customer'])
```

But this changes the value for all months. I'm lost on what to do next.

Comment: how do you know Customer 222 because a new customer on 2021-02-01? the new_customer column is 0

Comment: Customer 222 was new on 2021-01-01 so he is 1 the next month he is 0. I would like to change all months in that quarter to 1 for that customer.

Comment: Customer 222 has a value of `0` for every row in column new_customer in your sample data. how do you know when Customer 222 is a new customer?

Comment: This is what I see df =df.append({'date':'2021-01-01','ID':222, 'New_customer':1, 'Good_customer':'n', 'Quarter':1},ignore_index = True) in the 10th append statement.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at customer 111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Sort values first
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'date'])

# Assign a new column where you replace 0s with nan
# Groupby id and Quarter, then forward fill your 1s for 2 rows
df['New_customer'] = df.assign(na=df['New_customer'].replace(0, np.nan))\
.groupby(['ID', 'Quarter'])['na'].ffill(2).fillna(0).astype(int)

          date   ID  New_customer Good_customer Quarter
3   2021-01-01  111             0             y       1
4   2021-02-01  111             0             y       1
5   2021-03-01  111             0             y       1
0   2021-04-01  111             0             y       2
1   2021-05-01  111             0             y       2
2   2021-06-01  111             0             y       2
9   2021-01-01  222             1             n       1
10  2021-02-01  222             1             y       1
11  2021-03-01  222             1             y       1
6   2021-04-01  222             0             y       2
7   2021-05-01  222             0             y       2
8   2021-06-01  222             0             y       2
12  2021-05-01  333             1             n       2
13  2021-06-01  333             1             y       2
```